# In what scenarios does file globbing not work in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, glob, du

If I run `sudo du -sh <some_directory>/*` on a directory which requires root access it works and lists out the total sizes for all directories in . However I have found at least one scenario in which this does not happen:

`sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/*`

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html doesn't mention any scenarios in which this wouldn't be expected to work. Does anyone have any ideas why this might not work? Is it related to Docker or `du` or is it wholly related to globbing.

Comment: So, get root to do the glob expansion: `sudo sh -c 'du -sh /var/lib/docker/*'`

Comment: @sjnarv Your comment combined with glenn's would be a good answer. One of you should post it.

Comment: @glennjackman: See my previous comment.

Comment: Please don't post answers in comments; that's not what comments are for.

Comment: Thanks, @will-vousden; very helpful.

Comment: As to why: shell first performs the expansion and then runs the command. Hence, the globbing pattern is expanded without elevated privileges when using `sudo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments already mentioned it in brief, but to have a decent answer on the question and a more detailed explanation:

In the command

```
sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/*
```

The globbing you are performing takes place *before* the `sudo` is executed.  Only the call of `du` is done with root permissions.  That means if the directory `/var/lib/docker/` is restricted for you as a normal user and you cannot read it (missing `r` permissions), then the globbing asterisk will not evaluate to anything.  Default setting in the `bash` then is to leave it unchanged, so the string remains `/var/lib/docker/*`.

Then the arguments `du`, `-sh`, and `/var/lib/docker/*` are passed to `sudo` which then executes `du` with root permissions and passes the arguments `-sh` and `/var/lib/docker/*`.  `du` then tries to find a file with exactly this name and will probably find nothing because no file in there is named `*`.

Do achieve what you want you need to make the globbing be done with root permissions also.  For this you need to start a shell (only shells do the globbing) with root permissions:

```
sudo bash -c 'du -sh /var/lib/docker/*'
```

This way, the arguments `bash`, `-c` and `du -sh /var/lib/docker/*` are passed to the command `sudo`.  Then `sudo` starts the `bash` with root permissions and passes the commands `-c`, `du -sh /var/lib/docker/*`.  Then the `bash` understands because of the `-c` options that is supposed to evaluate and execute the command `du -sh /var/lib/docker/*`.  It then splits the command by spaces into the "words" `du`, `-sh`, and `/var/lib/docker/*`.  Now it performs any necessary globbing expansion (with root permissions, so it is allowed to read the contents of the directory `/var/lib/docker/`) on each of the words.  It will replace the last word by `/var/lib/docker/aufs`, `/var/lib/docker/builder`, `/var/lib/docker/buildkit`, and several more.  As a last step it will call `du` with `-sh` and the result of the globbing expansion.  Root permissions will be inherited for this, so `du` then also runs with them.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the /var/lib/docker folder does not exist on the host machine, only within the container.